# Store property in java

Tags: java, properties, ini

I am new here and in Java in general. I found this site useful to help me with application I am making. So far I managed to make it work and encountered on a store properties problem. Here is what I need.

I have table that load values from ini file upon form load. That part is working.

i have 2 global variables in dlgCene.java jDialog which is called from frmPorez.java jFrame:

```
private final Properties prop = new Properties();
private InputStream input = null;
```

When I open dlgCene that contains ucitajCene method all goes well. That method read all values from "cene.ini" file and populate fields in table.

here is the code:

On opening of dlgCene:

```
    private void formWindowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                  
      TableColumnModel tabela = tblCene.getColumnModel();
      tabela.getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(110); //Nepokretnost
      for(int row = 1; row <= 3; row++)
            frmPorez.alignRight(tblCene, row);
      ucitajCene();
   }
```

[image]

Now I want this. I change table cells value during runtime and want to save changes in ini file. I tried several things I found on Internet but can't make it work. If someone can point me to right directionit would be nice.

Last thing I tried is this:

[image]

I didn't get any error but value in "cene.ini" is not changed.

Comment: Please post your code as text and not in an image.

Comment: I tried but didn't managed. Sorry.

Comment: You could try 'println' instead of 'print'; it is possible that you're getting a message but that it is still buffered when the program ends. Are you sure you are looking for "cene.ini" in the right folder; the file will be written into the 'default' folder for the program, which may not be where you expect it.

Comment: Location is a problem, indeed. InputStream is loading from one location, and FileOutputStream is storing in another. I don't know how to make setCene FileOutputStream to use same location as InputStream. :(